How to increase the size of image continuously?
while pressing shiftkey ascept ratio will locked when we resize image image will maintained the ascept ration it will resize but when shift is not pressed in keybord while resize image it will resize normally? is it possible in React or anyother library for this problem?
I am trying ths code for resize imgae but i can't able to increase the size of image continuously?
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import './imageresize.css'
function Imageresize() {
const[image,setImage]=useState("")
const [dimension,setDimensions]=useState({ width:700, height: 600 })
const[shiftpressed,setShiftpressed]=useState(false)
const[aspectRatio]=useState(700/600)
const isResizingRef=useRef(false)
const startMouseRef=useRef({x:0,y:0})

    const handleImage=(e)=>{
        console.log(e.target.files)
        setImage(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        const handleKeyDown=(e)=>{
            if(e.key==="shift"){
                setShiftpressed(true)
            }}
        const handleKeyUp=(e)=>{
            if(e.key==="shift"){
                setShiftpressed(false)
                
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("keydown",handleKeyDown)
        window.addEventListener("keyup",handleKeyUp)
        return ()=>{
            window.removeEventListener("keydown",handleKeyDown)
            window.removeEventListener("keyup",handleKeyUp)
        }
    },[])
    const handleMouseDown=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        isResizingRef.current=true;
        startMouseRef.current=({x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY})
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    }
    const handleMouseMove=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        if(!isResizingRef.current){
            return;
        }
        const deltaX=e.clientX-startMouseRef.current.x
        const deltaY=e.clientY-startMouseRef.current.y
        if(shiftpressed){
            const newWidth=dimension.width+deltaX
            const newHeight=newWidth/aspectRatio
            setDimensions({width:newWidth,height:newHeight})
        }else{
            setDimensions({
                width:dimension.width+deltaX,
                height:dimension.height+deltaY
            })}
       }
    const handleMouseUp=()=>{
        isResizingRef.current=false
        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      }

return (
<div className='container'\>
<div className='input'\>
<input type='file' onChange={handleImage}/\>
</div\>
<div className='preview border border-2'\>
<div className='image'
style={{
position:"relative",
maxWidth:dimension.width,
maxHeight:dimension.height,
overflow:"hidden",
display:"flex",  
}}
onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
onMouseLeave={handleMouseUp}
onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}\>
{image && ( <\>
<img/>
<div
style={{position: "absolute",
bottom: 0,
right: 0,
width: "10px",
height: "10px",
cursor: "nwse-resize",}}
onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}\>

            </div>
            </>
            )}
       </div>
    </div>


  )
}
export default Imageresize


"is it possible in React or anyother library for this problem?" - Asking for recommendations on libraries, tools, etc. makes your question off-topic. What have you've tried to solve the issue? What is not working with the snippet posted? Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]
